# Problema al graficar con plotGoogleMaps

Tags: r

Hola soy nuevo graficando en R y tengo el siguiente problema.

Tengo unos puntos de muestra en un archivo XLSX.

```
Latitud             Longitud    Altura
19°10'40.11"N   97°38'15.45"O   2362
19°10'37.85"N   97°38'28.32"O   2361
19°10'36.21"N   97°38'27.47"O   2359
```

y mi codigo es el siguiente

```
library(plotGoogleMaps)

data.xlsx <- read.xlsx("AreaPrueba1.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
head(data.xlsx)

data.xlsx$Altura <-as.integer((as.character(data.xlsx$Altura)))

# creamos esta función para transformar las coordenadas geográficas a decimal
geo2dec<-function(c) {
  z<-sapply( strsplit(c, "[Â°\'\"]"), as.character )
  dec<- as.numeric(z[1, ]) + as.numeric(z[3, ])/60 + as.numeric(z[4, ])/3600
  if (z[5, ]=="N"||z[5, ]=="E") dec else -dec
}

data.xlsx$Latitud<-geo2dec(data.xlsx$Latitud)
data.xlsx$Longitud<-geo2dec(data.xlsx$Longitud)

#aqui el problema
pts <- data.frame(x=data.xlsx$Longitud,y=data.xlsx$Latitud)
coordinates(pts) <- ~x+y  
proj4string(pts) <- CRS('+init=epsg:32614')

m<-plotGoogleMaps(pts,filename='EjemploCampo.htm',mapTypeId='ROADMAP',layerName = 'Puntos de Medición')
```

Mi problema es que no entiendo como traducir las coordenadas correctamente para que me referencie bien los puntos , cambien el *+init=epsg:32614*, para la zona donde estan los puntos pero el mapa de salida me sale equivocado, me tira al mar.

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente tienes mal definida la proyección, o más bien no la has definido. Al hacer esto:

```
proj4string(pts) <- CRS('+init=epsg:32614')
proj4string(pts)

"+init=epsg:32614 +proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

Lo que ocurre es que el [código EPSG 32614](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32614/) tiene una proyección [`utm`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_coordenadas_universal_transversal_de_Mercator) (`+proj=utm`), cuando en realidad para los datos que tenemos entiendo, deberíamos configurar un proyección por lat/long. Una configuración recomendada para los mapas de google es esta:

```
proj4string(pts) <- CRS('+init=epsg:4326')
```

[Mas info](https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/~frazier/RSpatialGuides/OverviewCoordinateReferenceSystems.pdf)